# embed youtube video on an image at a specific location

Tags: php, html, youtube

I have an image on my page and i am trying to embed a youtube video on top of it at a specific location. How can i do this? usemap?

Comment: What do you mean by "on top"? z-index or higher up on the page?

Comment: yes, i want the zindex of the youtube on top of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, you would have to use CSS `position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;` syntax to align it but you would need the image to be a `background-image:` of the video's parent element.

```
<div style="background-image: url(image.jpg);">
<!--- embed youtube vid here with style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 100;" --->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might just have a terminology issue here;

Instead of thinking of 'embedding' something in the image - think instead of having a containing `div` wrapped around the video, with the image in question as the background. Then just use CSS to position the video within the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the html5 version of the video and use the poster attribute:

http://www.labnol.org/internet/embed-youtube-videos-in-html5-flash/14092/

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-html5-video/